# How can i adjust "-" in right place on print command

Tags: python

```
n = int(input("Age? "))

if n < 0:
    print("Error")
elif n < 5:
    print("I don't believe you can write...")
elif n > 5:
    print("Ok, you are" ,n,'-' + "years")
```

Prints out ok, you are xx -years
I need it to print ok, you are xx-years old

edit: thank everyone for help works like charm now.

Comment: The proper English orthography uses a space between the number and "years", like "You are 99 years old." (This is an error in Finnish, too; "olet 99 vuotta" but "olet 99-vuotias".)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the seperator:

```
print("Ok, you are" ,n, "-years", sep="")
```

Or you can use an f-string:

```
print(f"Ok, you are {n}-years")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
n = 24
print('Ok, you are {0}-years'.format(n))
```

Output:

```
Ok, you are 24-years old
```

Put together it will look like this:

```
n = int(input("Age? "))

if n < 0:
    print("Error")
elif n < 5:
    print("I don't believe you can write...")
elif n > 5:
    print('Ok, you are {0}-years'.format(n))
```

Answer (score 0):

The print() function concatenates its arguments with a separator, by default this separator is a space, however you can omit this separator and just add the strings like this:

```
print("Ok, you are " + n + '-' + "years")
```

To add more; this separator has its own argument you can change, for example:

```
print("a", "b", "c"+"d")
Output: a b cd

print("a", "b", "c"+"d", sep="-")
Output: a-b-cd
```